# Sscanf into pointer, with return

Tags: c

So I have a pointer (b), and I want to read numbers into that pointer, I can't fix it :\

```
double* 
scanner(double* b)
{
    while ((fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) && (line[0] != '\n'))
    {
        b =(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
        if (sscanf(line, "%lf\n", b[n]) == 1)
        {
            printf("%ld",b[n]);
        }

        n++;
    }

    return b;
}
```

Comment: `b = malloc(sizeof(double)*n);` doesn't do what you think it does. And the last statement is unreachable. And the format specifier for `double` in `printf` is `%f` or `%lf`.

Comment: it's C, not C++. remove the C++ tag. And post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `n = n++;` causes undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I suggest like this

```
double *bekerdezo2(size_t *n){
    double *b = NULL, value;
    *n = 0;

    while ((fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) && (line[0] != '\n')){
        if (sscanf(line, "%lf", &value) == 1){
            b = realloc(b, sizeof(*b) * (*n + 1));
            b[(*n)++] = value;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/HnfIGf)